# "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Flight' not found"

Tags: laravel

iam woking on laravel 5.7 , watching tutorial on laravel 5.2

in "laravel\routes\web.php"

```
Route::get('/flight ','makeflight@lol' );
```

in "laravel\App\Http\Controllers\makeflight.php"

```
   <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers ;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class makeflight extends Controller{
    public function lol(){
    $flights = Flight::all();
    $arr = array ('flights'=>$flights);
    return view('flight',$arr);
}}
```

in "laravel\App\Flight.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Flight extends Model{}
```

in "laravel\resources\views\flight.blade.php

```
<?php
echo $flights;
```

every thing is ok with migrations and database no doubt ;

> Error : "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Flight' not found"

I'm hard stuck in basics 
sorry if it was idiot, but it take like 10 hours from me and i searched alot.

Comment: add a `use App\Flight` in your controller.

Comment: error : "Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script"
just added it after " use Illuminate\Http\Request;"

Comment: solved ... thanks for help .. really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

you should add Flight model in top of page 
use App\Flight;

so your code should be like this:

```html
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers ;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Flight;
class makeflight extends Controller{
    public function lol(){
    $flights = Flight::all();
    $arr = array ('flights'=>$flights);
    return view('flight',$arr);
}}
```

Comment: error : "Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script"

Comment: maybe you have bom or space before your php tag 
by the way this question is about not found class 
another sections you can change it 
Good luck